# Pandas left merge using cumcount to avoid duplicate rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to perform a left merge on the `output_df` if the column `id` exists in another dataframe called `incorrect`. Because I am not allowed to drop duplicates, I used the `cumcount` method suggested online. For some reasons, the code will incorrectly flag a row when the `id` and `helper` are unique and does not exist in the `incorrect` dataframe. I would really appreciate if someone could let me know what the issue with the code is. Thanks!

```
#Codes I am running right now
incorrect['helper'] = incorrect.groupby('id').cumcount()
output_df['helper'] = output_df.groupby('id').cumcount()

output_df = output_df.merge(incorrect, on=['id', 'helper'], how='left', 'Result'=field).drop('helper', axis=1)

output_df['Result'] = (output_df['Result'] == 'both')
output_df['Result'] = np.where(output_df['Result'], 'Fail', 'Pass')
```

```
#output_df
id helper
A  0
A  1
B  0
B  1
B  2
C  0
D  0
```

```
#incorrect
id helper
A  0
A  1
B  0
B  1
```

```
#Results right now, which are not what I expected
id helper Result
A  0      Fail
A  1      Fail
B  0      Fail
B  1      Fail
B  2      Fail # I would expect this row to be Pass because this record does not exist in the incorrect dataframe
C  0      Pass
D  0      Pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:

try:

pass `indicator=True` in `merge()` and after that map values

```
output_df=output_df.merge(incorrect, on=['id', 'helper'], how='left',indicator=True)
output_df['_merge']=output_df['_merge'].map({'both':'Fail','left_only':'Pass'})
#you can also use replace() method in place of map()
```

output of `output_df`:

```
id  helper  _merge
0   A   0   Fail
1   A   1   Fail
2   B   0   Fail
3   B   1   Fail
4   B   2   Pass
5   C   0   Pass
6   D   0   Pass
```